# Loop function yet break if certain code put into raw_input

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I've been looking up on here and Google yet can't find the solution for what I'm looking for. "While" function keeps failing me as I don't know here I need to put it. I'm a total newbie so if you could kindly explain the solution, thank you:

```
number = raw_input("Number: ")
if int(number) % 2 == 0:
  print "Even number"
else:
  print "Odd number"
```

All I would like to do is to keep the function looping allowing the user to enter as many numbers as possible. It should only break if user puts in "stop" as the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if user types stop, program stops.So we need to check for that when we create our while loop like:

```
number_from_user = raw_input("Number: ")
while number_from_user != "stop":
    try:
        if int(number_from_user)% 2 == 0:
            print "Even number"
        else:
            print "Odd number"
        number_from_user = raw_input("Number:")
    except ValueError:
         print("Enter a number please")
         number_from_user = raw_input("Number:")
```

And I suggest you make yourself familiar with **while** **loops**, which I found a video explaining and making an example "Guess the number game" using python. It should help **you** enough to make you able to solve your own problem with while loops.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tu0zlBFRa_c

or:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PoPxclbw6uc

And I suppose you're using python 2.7, in those videos they're using python 3+, you should type raw_input where they're typing input.

Edited: Added try and except.

Comment: mind you this will create a strange case if user enters "asjdıajsdıajs" or something, python int() build in function cant convert strings, so it will throw an error if you enter a string instead a number, and exit the program

Comment: Thank you for this - I've seen this earlier, how can we over come this? Can we write an if statement to say that if anything other than int/number, print "sorry, numbers only" etc. if that makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: You can actually, with a try and except, like try: number_from_user = int(number_from_user) except ValueError: print "give me a number pls" number_from_user = raw_input("Number: ") well since I'm not on computer atm cant type much sorry

Comment: Ok found the solution: We can use if function to see if it's a digit/alpha and process it from there. if number_from_user.isdigit():